# glGetIntegerv() segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opengl

I am getting a segmentation fault in OpenGL when i run glGetIntegerv() in my program

here is the full program

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Shader sources
const GLchar vertexSource[] =
"#version 430 core\n"
"layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition"
"void main() {"
"   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
"}";

const GLchar fragmentSource[] =
"#version 430 core\n"

"out vec4 fColor"
"void main() {"
"   fColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,1.0, 1.0);"
"}";

int main(){

glfwInit();

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);          
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit();


//Create Vertex Array Object
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

// Create a Vertex Buffer Object and copy the vertex data to it
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);


GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
};

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


GLint * name;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, name);


//printf(" %d \n", *kay);



}
```

the program doesnt give me any errors before if i take out the glGetIntegerv() function out , so it has definitely something to do with that , and yes i do realize that the program isnt complete , but surely the glGetIntegerv has nothing to do with that, it should be accessing my gpu for that information

Comment: `name` is uninitialized

Comment: _"Here is the full program"_ That's not a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as expected here. Use a debugger first, narrow it down. SO isn't an online debugging service!

Comment: i did use a debugger and it didnt give me any indication that the name is uninitialized

Comment: okay so clearly it was the uninitialized name sorry for missing that and wasting your time

Answer (score 3):

`name` is an uninitialized pointer. It will usually have some garbage value, meaning that it could point to any possible location. Writing to it is undefined behavior, and will usually result in something like segmentation fault.

In fact, you don't need pointer here:

```
GLint name;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &name);
```

Comment: yeah i figured it out, i was tired and i didnt realize what i was writing when i wrote that, and yes i actually did change it to just int value and used address of operator, as soon as jozxyqk pointed out an uninitialized pointer i realized i missed that

Comment: also everyone missed the other mistake i had in there, see if you can spot it, actually there is two(one is more obvious then the other which is more api specific)

Comment: @hopjoppe5 this site is not about games and guessing. You'd better post the problem you found as another answer, for example.

Comment: i already solved both the problem all i was saying that everyone missed an obvious error, if they were able to notice an uninitialized pointer they should have noticed the missing variable, never mind, the problems are both solved